# continuously play youtube videos using video IDs

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I have an array of youtube video Ids. I want to create a sort of continuous play playlist using the youtube APIs. How can i do this using PHP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to get PHP into the mix here. A standard YouTube HTML player embed with custom player parameters will let you do that.

Take a look at the documentation for the [playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#playlist) and [loop](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop) parameters.

Comment: i feel like a complete idiot. thank you good sir.